# Move from a frame to a frame in Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

Unfortunately, our team leader has decided that we'll use Swing for this light desktop app. I have no previous experience in working with Swing. I will be working on the GUI side of the project. I've already created a frame with elements within it and wrote the logic in the event listeners. Now I want to redirect the user to a new frame after he's logged in.

How do I do that? Thanks

P.S. I'd appreciate if you could point me to a good tutorial for beginners

Comment: have a look at the tutorial referenced in the swing tag wiki

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you have your terminology mixed up.  When we hear "Frame" we think `JFrame` which is equivalent to "Window".  So most of the time we'd recommend not using multiple windows, but changing the content of the window.  The content is generally made with a "JPanel".

So generally, you set up your `JFrame`, you set the content with this:

```
JPanel loginPanel = new JPanel();
frame.setContentPane(loginPanel);
```

If you want to replace your login panel with a new panel, just pass the new panel to that function:

```
JPanel mainMenuPanel = new JPanel();
frame.setContentPane(mainMenuPanel);
```

(of course you want some content in those panels)

Here's a simple example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PanelRetriever{

    Box panel1;
    JPanel panel2;

    public PanelRetriever(final JFrame frame){
        //Build the first login panel
        panel1 = Box.createVerticalBox();
        panel1.setBackground(Color.orange);
        panel1.setOpaque(true);
        panel1.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
        panel1.add(new JTextField(10));
        JButton login = new JButton("Login");
        login.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                frame.setContentPane(getPanel2());
                frame.validate();
            }});
        panel1.add(login);
        panel1.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());

        //Build second panel
        panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setBackground(Color.blue);
        panel2.setOpaque(true);
        JButton logout = new JButton("Logout");
        logout.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.setContentPane(getPanel1());
                frame.validate();
            }});
        panel2.add(logout, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public Container getPanel1(){
        return panel1;
    }

    public Container getPanel2(){
        return panel2;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                PanelRetriever pr = new PanelRetriever(frame);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
                frame.setContentPane(pr.getPanel1());
                frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give me complete simple example of what you told in the answer, i get your point above but could not succeed to implement it as i am beginner to swing.and i don't want to use multiple jframe in my gui application.

Comment: @Mihir I added an example so you could see the code in action.

Answer (score 4):

Your frame should stay the same, just create and show new JPanel instead old one.

See below JPanel  painting process:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As @Gilbert Le Blanc has pointed out (+1 to him). In Swing it is [bad practice to use multiple `JFrame`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice).

To accomplish what you want:

- Use [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) which allows dynamic switching of components
- Or use `JFrame#removeAll()` and add a new `JPanel` (+1 Fess)
- Try using `JDialog`/`JOptionPane` and then redirect to main `JFrame`
  here is a good link on the topic: [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Answer (score 3):

In Swing, you have one `JFrame`.  You use `JDialog`s to get user id and password input from the user.

Here's a link to the [Oracle Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a new frame in much the same way as you already have;

```
MyFrame f = new MyFrame(); //MyFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame
```

And then bring it to the front with;

```
f.setVisible(true);
f.toFront();
```

Comment: but I dont want to dynamically create the frame in code. I will create it through the designer..

Comment: A new `JFrame` will create a new *frame*, that is a new 'window' on your desktop, leaving the old one where it is. If you just want to change the content, then swap out a new `JPanel`.

Comment: its bad practice to use multiple JFrames:     Bad (bad, bad) practice.

User unfriendly: The user sees multiple icons in their task bar when expecting to see only one. Plus the side effects of the coding problems..
A nightmare to code and maintain:
A modal dialog offers the easy opportunity to focus attention on the content of that dialog - choose/fix/cancel this, then proceed. Multiple frames do not.
A dialog (or floating tool-bar) with a parent will come to front when the parent is clicked on - you'd have to implement that in frames if that was the desired behavior.

Comment: bad practice, maybe. bad user experience? that really depends, it might be that you want to give the impression of starting a new application without having to do IPC. either way, the question was how to switch from one frame to a new frame, which is what my answer provides, in its most simple form.

Comment: @Fess  Gee that sounds familiar. ;)

Comment: I think @Fess makes a good point (& yes, I am biased), this is so often a "How can I shoot myself in the foot?" question that it pays to be absolutely sure the use-case justifies it before explaining the how.  I have yet to find a situation that does justify it.